# List of Integers into byte array

Tags: java, list, integer, arrays

I have a **LinkedList < Integer >** with big size (3912984 or more) and I wanna copy these elements in a byte array. The integers are 0 or 1, so I don't need any change of size for array, I want just to copy elements one by one, exactly how they are. Of course, I know the simplest way is :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)      
 array[i] = (byte)(int) list.get(i);
```

But this method is too slow and my program doesn't end before hours ! Can you know another way (faster, something like Buffer.BlockCopy() of .NET) or I have to change data structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is byteValue() method available in Number class.  Number is extended by Integer, Double, Float etc.

```
List<Integer> list = getNumbers();

Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext())
{
   Integer i = iterator.next()
   byteArray[index] = i.byteValue();
}
```

You can also use `java.nio.MappedByteBuffer` class for block copy.  see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html.

MappedByteBuffer is equivalent to Buffer.BlockCopy()  in .NET

Comment: @Fabrizio, one contributing factor to the performance is that `list.get(index)` is a linear time operation for a `LinkedList`.  Given that you are looping over the whole list, this makes your algorithm as written quadratic.  If you use Mr. D Luffy's approach here, using iterators, it will become overall linear and *much* faster.

Comment: @msandiford for each loop in java uses iterator internally right ? It requires iterable interface implemented to iterate through for each loop. I am not sure about it.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy yes, the foreach loop uses an Iterator.

Comment: Oracle docs says so http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it with Java 8:

```
List<Integer> enteros = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).collect(Collectors.toList());
Byte[] bytes = enteros.stream().map(entero -> entero.byteValue()).toArray(Byte[]::new);
```

Here another complex example to test the conversion time:

```
List<Integer> enteros = new LinkedList<>();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println("Init list: " + LocalTime.now().format(formatter));
// Fill array with 0 and 1
for(int i = 0; i < 9999999; i++) enteros.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 2));
System.out.println("List complete: " + LocalTime.now().format(formatter));

System.out.println("Init list convert: " + LocalTime.now().format(formatter));
Byte[] bytes = enteros.stream().map(entero -> entero.byteValue()).toArray(Byte[]::new);
System.out.println("End convert! " + LocalTime.now().format(formatter));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// example input list
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(0);
list.add(1);
list.add(0);
list.add(1);
list.add(1);

// write to byte array
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
for (int element : list) {
    out.writeUTF(Integer.toString(element));
}
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

// read from byte array
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bais);
while (in.available() > 0) {
    String element = in.readUTF();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Comment: This is not what was asked for - it doesn't retain the bytes *as they are*, but converts them to ASCII.